# How to disable Touch-ID on MacBooks via keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut, touch-id, face-id

On iOS I can disable Face-ID by pressing a specific combination of keys.

For example, when I press the power button five times in a row on my iPhone 11, it will be locked and Face-ID is disabled until it is unlocked again.

I'm looking for the same on MacOS. Currently I'm using a M1 MacBook Air.

Pressing the Touch-ID button three times opens the Accessibility Shortcuts.

**Edit:**

On a different channel the `bioutil` command line tool was mentioned. To disable Touch-ID, run the following command: `sudo bioutil -w -s -u 0`.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/afk3o0/comment/hlobtbf/

Mentioned:

- https://mastodon.social/@stagen/110116972326763900
- https://mastodon.social/@stagen/110116993396491946

I see this as an alternative to what I'm looking for because it is too cumbersome to use compared to the iOS equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

you can disable the accessibility shortcuts in
settings -> accessibility -> shortcut

then it will require password after couple (5) wrong finger-touches

Comment: Thanks, but using the wrong finger until it is locked feels like a workaround.